# inserting data into postgres to relational table

Tags: postgresql

It has been a while since I wrote queries by hand, and I am having trouble inserting data into a relational OneToOne entity. What I need is for the id of the inserted course to be returned so I can insert it into the Course_Content entity.

```sql
OneToOne
course -> course_details

OneToOne
course_details -> course_content

OneToMany
course_content -> videos

INSERT INTO Courses(title, description, lessons, duration) VALUES ('A crash course','An awesome crash course','33','4 Hours') RETURNING id;
INSERT INTO Course_Content(id, section_title) values (id, 'A pretty awesome crash course');
```

I have also tried

```
INSERT INTO Courses(title, description, lessons, duration) VALUES ('A crash course','An awesome crash course','33','4 Hours');
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('Courses','id'));
INSERT INTO Course_Content(section_title) values ('A pretty awesome crash course');
```

Error

```
[23503] ERROR: insert or update on table "course_content" violates foreign key constraint "coursedetail_fk" Detail: Key (id)=(1) is not present in table "course_detail".
```

How can I insert with a relation id?

The problem is with the second `INSERT` statement - I cannot use the id. Here is the entire SQL code to create the necessary relations:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Courses(
    id SERIAL,
    title varchar(256),
    description varchar(256),
    lessons varchar(256),
    duration varchar(256),
    CONSTRAINT CoursesPK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Course_Detail(
    id SERIAL,
    title varchar(256),
    instructor varchar(256),
    introduction varchar(256),
    learn varchar(256),
    topics varchar(256),
    prerequisites varchar(256),
    goal varchar(256),
    additional_details varchar(256),
    highlevel_overview varchar(256),
    CONSTRAINT Course_fk FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Courses(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    CONSTRAINT CourseDetailPK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Course_Content(
    id SERIAL,
    section_title varchar(256),
    CONSTRAINT CourseDetail_fk FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Course_Detail(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    CONSTRAINT CourseContentPK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Videos(
    id SERIAL,
    title varchar(256),
    url varchar(256),
    paid bool,
    length varchar(256),
    CONSTRAINT CourseContent_fk FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Course_Content(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    CONSTRAINT VideosPK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO Courses(title, description, lessons, duration) VALUES ('A crash course','An awesome crash course','33','4 Hours') RETURNING id;
INSERT INTO Course_Content(id, section_title) values (id, 'A pretty awesome crash course');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CONSTRAINT Course_fk FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Courses(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
```

This constraint here is funky. Your foreign key column is an auto-generated column that you can't insert directly into. I think your intention is this...

```
course_id INT,
CONSTRAINT Course_fk FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES Courses(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
```

Adding this extra column allows the id to point to whatever and not be constrained by the rules of the `SERIAL` data type.

For utilizing the id in the query, I like doing subqueries based on the business id instead of trying to retrieve the newly inserted id val. From the perspective of the application, you should separate these two statements out to be able to clearly log where the error is. So your code would retrieve the ID from the previous statement to create the new subobject then insert it

```
INSERT INTO Course_Content
(section_title, content_id) 
values 
('A pretty awesome crash course', 
(SELECT id FROM Courses where title = ''))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you are correct. But how can Insert using the `course_id` . I tried `SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('Courses','id')) as id;` and then using `INSERT INTO Course_Content(section_title, content_id) values ('A pretty awesome crash course', id)`  but I am not able to access the id. When I manually enter the ID I get the fk exception. I would like to insert in one statement with all the relations.

Comment: @Mike3355 I expanded on that a little bit in an edit